# How can I map an image correctly over my texture?

Tags: materials

My image preview is correct in how the image is supposed to look and doesn't look anything like I need it to.

This is how it should look

[image: pill bottle label]

This is what I got so far, as you can see I need the label to be up higher on the bottle and lower on the bottle[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the blend file? It could be a few things: your uv map is probably the cause.

Comment: @BenSmith next time please pack the images used for the file...

Comment: I have one image and I clicked pack all into .blend from the external data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a subsurf modifier you are experiencing interpolation issues over the large polygons on the label.

Add a few cuts on the edges of the label:

[image]

[image]

Then select the area for the label, unwrap it again and scale and rotate the UVs to get something like this:

[image]

Where the UV mapping uses the top and bottom of the image and is twice as wide as the image (since it will use the image for the front and back of the bottle).

Comment: Also the model should have scale applied (`Ctrl`+`A`).

Comment: I just clicked on simple from the subsurf modifier and it made it fit. Thanks

Comment: @BenSmith the simple form of the subsurf will not give you the same "roundness" on the bottle...

Answer (score 0):

For the darkness, use this material node setup:[image]

It will allow you to have a relatively shadeless image. Tweak the selected value to decide how luminescent you want your model to be.

As for the UV mapping, this is a complicated subject, but Ken Loge does a good job of going over the basics [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il7ajiCepus). Also, consider Blender Guru [here](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-anisotropic-shading/). For what I can say, you will want to have a triangle fan at the top and bottom of your cylindrical design and edge select all of the top edges and one along the side. Then key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select Mark Seam. Next, press <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice until everything is selected. After that, key <kbd>U</kbd> and select Unwrap. If you do this correctly, it will give you the spiky rectangle thing on the left (a UV Map), which you can Grab (<kbd>G</kbd>) to move around and Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) to change the size of your image in relation to the eventual result (all of that is pictured above). You may also want to consider this: [image]